# For statement - really odd output (Batch Files)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following batch statement:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.lst) do set "offendingfile=%%x"
```

Although for some really odd reason, when it is called it outputs:

```
"C:\Windows\calc.exe "
```

instead of

```
"C:\Windows\calc.exe"
```

Since there is a trailing space, I can't use it properly with any other statements in the batch file, does anyone know why it does this and how to fix this, as its been driving me nuts!

Comment: You might find [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch/3002207#3002207) useful.

Answer (score 1):

does your `file.lst` file has a trailing space after the file name?

I checked this with file.lst having: `c:\windows\calc.exe` and the output was correct, but if the file.lst file contains `c:\windows\calc.exe<SPACE>`, the output is the same that you are getting (and is the expected output as well).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `delims=` portion of the `for` statement is removing the default behavior of using spaces as delimiters.  If you remove that portion, then it should remove the trailing blank:

```
for /f %%x in (file.lst) do set "offendingfile=%%x"
```

Comment: This does solve the problem of trailing blanks as well as introduce another one, of incomplete paths/names, like `Program Files`.

Comment: @Andriy:  Yes, you are correct.   For tasks like this, it is often easier to resort to something like Ruby, Python, Perl, etc.  If the OP is using something like [Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/index.html), then functions like @trim are available.  Otherwise it might require something like is [suggested here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.TrimRightFOR)