# How to run a batch file for every user returned in list by command net user?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

My goal is to make a universal code which loops through all user account names in a computer and sends the output to a batch file. The "net user" command outputs a list of users but I want to assign each user name to an argument. So I should use the `for /f` command to do it. This may look easy, but remember user names may include spaces at any place: at the beginning, at the end or in the middle, Also, it's possible to find 2 consecutive spaces

Hint 1: The maximum length of a user name is 20 characters
Hint 2: The loops needs to iterate through wrong user names so it needs to check if they're valid. The command `net user "uName"` sets `%ErrorLevel%` to 0 if the user name "uName" (for example) is valid.

If there's no way possible, maybe a VBScript could start the batch file with each of the user account names.

**Edit:** I finally made my own code, but it takes about 5 seconds for only 15 accounts.

I would like a better solution, maybe with another programming language.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "skip=4 delims=" %%I in ('net user') do (
    Set "Line=%%I"
    If not "!Line:~-1,1!" == "." for %%I in (0,25,50) do (
        Set "Name=!Line:~%%I,20!"
        Call :setName
    )
)

Set Name=
:setName
If not "!Name!" == "" (
    Net user "!Name!" && %~dp0Test.bat "!Name!"
    If not "!Name:~-1,1!" == " " goto:eof
    Set "Name=!Name:~0,-1!"
    Goto setName
)

endlocal
```

Comment: please finish your phrase "may include spaces at the "

Comment: and please specify if your need is to pipe the user list to another batch file OR as argument OR start the batch file 1 time for each user

Comment: Show us what you've written so far.

Comment: You could start with `for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('net USER') do @For %U in (%G) do @echo user = %U` command to get a start point, first preview of `FOR` command. Then learn more [e.g. here](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: @Florent I've finished my phrase (btw u france?), and I want start the batch file 1 time for each user.

Comment: that won't be easy with pure batch, does powershell fit your requirements ?

Comment: @Florent Thanks for reasing the edit made to the post

Answer (score 1):

A user account name with a space at beginning or end of name is according to my tests not possible. Spaces can be only between non whitespace characters in a user account name.

Here is my commented batch solution which is also not very fast.

```
@echo off
rem Process output of command 'net user' line by line with skipping
rem the first 4 lines and stopping processing when line with success
rem message is reached which of course depends on language of Windows.
for /F "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%L in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user`) do (
    if "%%L"=="The command was successfully executed." goto :EOF
    call :ProcessAccounts "%%L"
)
goto :EOF

rem Subrountine to process a line with user account names.
:ProcessAccounts
rem Get the line without the double quotes.
set "Line=%~1"

:NextUser
rem Get first 20 characters from line and next remove those 20 characters.
set "Name=%Line:~0,20%"
set "Line=%Line:~20%"

rem Remove all spaces at end of current user account name.
:TrimRight
if "%Name:~-1%"==" " (
    set "Name=%Name:~0,-1%"
    goto TrimRight
)

rem Check if this user account name is valid.
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%Name%" 1>nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Valid user account name is: %Name%
    rem Do here what should be done with this user account name.
)

rem Remove leading spaces from remaining line.
:TrimLeft
if "%Line:~0,1%"==" " (
    set "Line=%Line:~1%"
    goto TrimLeft
)

rem Is the shortened line now completely processed?
if not "%Line%"=="" goto NextUser

rem Exit the subroutine ProcessAccounts.
goto :EOF
```

There is perhaps a better solution for trimming spaces left and right, see [How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/)

The reason for the slow execution speed of this batch file is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%Name%" 1>nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Valid user account name is: %Name%
    rem Do here what should be done with this user account name.
)
```

By changing this block to just

```
echo Valid user account name is: %Name%
rem Do here what should be done with this user account name.
```

makes the batch file much, much faster.

The validation of user account name with `net user "%Name%"` makes the batch file so slow.

Comment: It's possible to have left/right spaces, try { net user "  testuser  " /add } then type { net user testuser } and you won't find it

Comment: Also, a user name can not include a "." so you could just check if the line "The command was successfully executed." ends with a point instead of comparing the whole line. Finally, each line contains a maximum of 3 user names, the first starts at the 1st character, the second at 26th, the 3rd at 51th so you could use this instead of trimming left. Also, "Guest" and "Guest " could be 2 different users so you should check for every space at the right if the user name is valid. I know i could end up with the file running twice with the exact same username but it doesn't matter for me.

Comment: I entered a user name with leading and trailing spaces on GUI where the dialog trimmed the spaces on pressing OK. It looks like the Microsoft developer who wrote `net user` source code forgot to trim spaces. And I read on [Creating User and Group Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx) on MSDN that since Windows 2000 a user account name (logon name) can have up to 104 characters. So my solution is not really working in general at all. It will practically work for 99.9% of all user account names, but definitely not for all. A period is allowed according to MSDN article.

Comment: of course, the net user command is very old so they must have forgot to trim spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line powershell proposition :

```
foreach ($account in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName . -ErrorAction Stop) { myscript.bat $account.Name}
```

you can store in a .ps1 file and execute with `powershell myfile.ps1`

If you need more than just local account you will have to mess with the `-Filter` parameter.
Also, any account name with spaces will be passed with surrounding quotes, you need to cope with in the callee batch script.