# Batch File -Send Message to all users except one

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

Hi guys i want to send a message to all the users logged into a windows machine(Server 2012) except for one user.I know i can use the msg command to send the message but as far as i have seen it does not have any syntax where i can ignore sending message to one user alone. 
Msg *  <- sends to all users which is what i dont want.
msg username | sessionid etc would have been fine but this script will be run automatically so everything needs to be dynamic.

So if possible i want a batch file which can find out list of users logged into a machine and send a message to all these users except for one user say usernameX which i specify.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a batch file or a powershell script?

Comment: Also, just to reiterate it, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I despise creating something that already exists, so I found a way to retrieve users on a computer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935615/how-to-run-a-batch-file-for-every-user-returned-in-list-by-command-net-user)

Though of course the vagueness of your question means you may be asking a different question, in which case let me know.

Take this within a chunk of code in afformentioned link;

```
    echo Valid user account name is: %Name%
    rem Do here what should be done with this user account name.
```

And replace it with a simple `if` command for your `usernameX`, running your `msg * <-` to all else.

```
 if %name% neq usernameX (
  msg * <- Hello, i am text!
)
```