# cmd read content from file and removing extra space in the end

Tags: cmd

In a batch file I am reading the content of a file to `version` parameter

```
set /p version=<"\\10.10.20.13\Versions Control\File.txt"
```

in `File.txt` the value is `This is a text` with an extra space in the end

How can I read the content of File.txt and trim the extra space after the last char `This is a text`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set` again to extract part of a variable (substring).

```
set /p version=<"\\10.10.20.13\Versions Control\File.txt"
set result=%version:~0,-1%
```

- `~0` don't skip any characters (start at the beginning)
- `-1` keeps all characters except the last one.

---

Source [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>   %variable:~num_chars_to_skip%
>   %variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
> ```
>
> This can include negative numbers:
>
> ```
>   %variable:~num_chars_to_skip, -num_chars_to_keep%
>   %variable:~-num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
>   %variable:~-num_chars_to_skip,-num_chars_to_keep%
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> SET _test=123456789abcdef0
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ::Extract everything BUT the last 7 characters
>
> ```
> SET _result=%_test:~0,-7%
> ECHO %_result% =123456789
> ```