# Batch scripting: output is empty when trying to echo file content

Tags: batch-file, wmic

i'm trying to loop through all installed programs:

```
wmic /output:C:\temp\InstallList.txt product get name

for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (C:\temp\InstallList.txt) do echo %%G
```

the file is created, but the output is empty!

Comment: Don't use WMIC and batch and use PowerShell instead.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Switching to PowerShell fixed my issue with a poorly written installer. The installer prompts the user for various "0 / 1 / 2" options for continue / exit / reinstall. For some reason, using `echo 1 | setup.exe` was feeding blank input to the installer when run in Windows batch / cmd.exe. However running the exact same command in PowerShell worked. Possibly a similar Unicode issue described by the other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not empty. The output is in Unicode. Use `more` to convert into current local encoding.

If you would like the whitespace removed from the end of the strings, see [How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
wmic product get name | more >"C:\temp\InstallList.txt"
for /F "skip=1 usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (`type "C:\temp\InstallList.txt"`) do (
    set S=%%G
    set S=!S:~0,-1!
    if "!S!" NEQ "" (echo !S!)
)
```

Comment: 1. your second line will not work, the `usebackq` option is missing! 2. your first line works, although there is going to be some noise in the output file (superfluous carriage-returns); this may cause trouble when reading (e. g., use `echo "%%G"` in your second line, then you'll notice that some closing quotes will disappear...);

Comment: You are right @aschipfl. I have edited the code to change the for loop as well as handle the extraneous \r that wmic emits.

Comment: Thank you, @Liturgist! there is an even easier and more secure approach to get rid of the additional CRs: inside of `for /F %%G`, just place another loop `for /F "delims=" %%F in ("%%G") do echo "%%F"; so you will not need delayed expansion, and there is no risk of removing too much;

Answer (score 0):

Could just do it all in one

```
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('wmic product get name') do @echo %%G
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Unicode format of the output of the `wmic` command. Hence your file `InstallList.txt` contains many `0x00` bytes which cause the `for /F` loop to terminate.

To work around that, capture the `wmic` output with a `for /F` loop, so it becomes converted to non-Unicode format:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('
    wmic PRODUCT GET Name
') do echo %%G
```

The `skip=1` option removes the header `Name` from the output.

Unfortunately, the output still contains some disturbing artefacts (in fact, there are some orphaned carriage-returns). To get rid of them, nest another `for /F` loop:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('
    wmic PRODUCT GET Name
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ("%%G") do echo %%F
)
```

---

Of course you can parse your Unicode output file `InstallList.txt` with `for /F`, but you cannot do it directly, you need to use the `type` command to do the conversion to non-Unicode:

```
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('
    type "C:\temp\InstallList.txt"
') do rem the rest is the same as above
```

You can also use the `more` command to achieve that, by simply writing `more` instead of `type`.

---

You might notice that each line returned by the `echo` command contains trailing spaces. If they disturb you, you might use the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "REPL=    "
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('
    wmic PRODUCT GET Name
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ("%%G") do (
        set "LINE=%%F%REPL%"
        set "TRNC=!LINE:*%REPL%=%REPL%!"
        call echo %%LINE:!TRNC!=%%
    )
)
endlocal
```

What I am doing here is:

- to specify a sequence of spaces (4 in this example, assuming that each line contains less spaces in its part of interest) in variable `REPL`;
- to read each line, to append the sequence of spaces and to store the augmented line in `LINE`;
- to retrieve the actual sequence of trailing spaces per line (by seeking the sequence in `REPL`) and to store it in `TRNC`;
- to replace the actual sequence of spaces of each line by nothing, that is, to truncate it, and then to actually output the remaining string portion;

Of course you can do this too when parsing the file `InstallList.txt` as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!