# Output of WMIC command in variable

Tags: batch-file

```
for %%f in ('wmic service where 'name like 'Steam Client%%'") do set Service=%%f
echo %Service%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the output and what's your expectation?

Comment: Im looking for the batch file to return me the service name and it will ask me whether to stop/start the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

The second for loop strips some problematic characters from the output, much in the same way as the `FindStr` example, only quicker. I then implement a `Call` to strip the trailing spaces which pad the end of the returned `Get` string.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC Service Where (Name Like 'Steam%%') Get Name"'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Echo("%Service%"
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "Service=%*"
GoTo :EOF
```

*The above code is completely untested as I'm using an android device.*

Comment: Thats more like it :D :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic service where "name like "Steam%%"" get Name ^| findstr /V /R "^$"') do set Service=%%f
echo %SERVICE%
```

**Output**

```
Steam Client Service
```

Mistakes in your code:

- Did not use `/F` switch with for-loop
- Used single and double-quotes intermixed.
- Did not specify a specific property to get with the `get` clause
- Did not filter extra output with `findstr`

Comment: This out put "Steam Client Service" is giving me trailing spaces. Like "Steam Client Service           (spaces)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the last bracket in `('wmic service where 'name like 'Steam Client%%'")` supposed to be ' not " ? In any case, I have never tried to use wmic service, only wmic win32_localtime which looked like this: `FOR /F %%F IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek^|Findstr [0-6]') DO SET DOW=%%F`

EDIT: I notice several places where you have gone wrong here, at least in the parts that I can understand. If you want the output of the code to be evaluated by a FOR statement you require /F infront of FOR and before the variable. You also normally need to start and end the brackets containing the command with a single quote ('). Like so: `for /f %%f in ('wmic service where name like "Steam Client%%"') do set Service=%%f
echo %Service%`

For any assistance with WMIC queries [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/) might help

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the batch file to find the name of the service and display it on screen. Thank You for your quick response.

Comment: Did you note the first relevant part of this answer? Where you are supposed to have the command within the brackets needs to be ended (and started) with a single quote ('). and then the second part, where I showed what I had done with a for command to use a command. You require /F in front of FOR if you are using a command in the statement.